# How to localize all numbers among Text?

Tags: java, android, localization

In android, I can localize numbers with:

```
String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", xxxxx)
```

Here the "xxxxx" must contain only numbers. What if, there is a case which numbers are mixed with text in a TextView. I fixed this by replacing all the English numbers with their equals in a for loop, but is there a best way to do this localization?
Example:

```
 String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s", "The identification number is : 1234567");
```

Numbers in this example are not changing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helped.

```
NumberFormat num_format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
String your_string = num_format.format(1000000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I asked.